# How do I divide a given image into 8 unique pie segments?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am pretty new to Python and want to do the following: I want to divide the following image into 8 pie segments:

[image: Original image]

I want it to look something like this (I made this in PowerPoint):

[image: Sketch]

The background should be black and the edge of the figure should have an unique color as well as each pie segment.

**EDIT:** I have written a code that divides the whole image in 8 segments:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
im=Image.open('C:/Users/20191881/Documents/OGO Beeldanalyse/Python/asymmetrie/rotation.png')
fill = 255
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.line((0,0) + im.size, fill)    
draw.line((0, im.size[1], im.size[0], 0), fill) 
draw.line((0.5*im.size[0],0, 0.5*im.size[0], im.size[1]), fill)   
draw.line((0, 0.5*im.size[1], im.size[0], 0.5*im.size[1]), fill)  
del draw
im.show()
```

The output gives:

[image: Output]

The only thing that is left to do is to find a way to make each black segment inside the border an unique color and also give all the white edge segments an unique color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code divides the image in eight parts, that's correct, but with respect to the image center, you don't get eight "angular equally" pie segments like you show in your sketch.

Here would be my solution, only using Pillow and the `math` module:

```py
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def segment_color(i_color, n_colors):
    r = int((192 - 64) / (n_colors - 1) * i_color + 64)
    g = int((224 - 128) / (n_colors - 1) * i_color + 128)
    b = 255
    return (r, g, b)


# Load image; generate ImageDraw
im = Image.open('path_to/vgdrD.png').convert('RGB')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

# Number of pie segments (must be an even number)
n = 8

# Replace (all-white) edge with defined edge color
edge_color = (255, 128, 0)
pixels = im.load()
for y in range(im.height):
    for x in range(im.width):
        if pixels[x, y] == (255, 255, 255):
            pixels[x, y] = edge_color

# Draw lines with defined line color
line_color = (0, 255, 0)
d = min(im.width, im.height) - 10
center = (int(im.width/2), int(im.height)/2)
for i in range(int(n/2)):
    angle = 360 / n * i
    x1 = math.cos(angle/180*math.pi) * d/2 + center[0]
    y1 = math.sin(angle/180*math.pi) * d/2 + center[1]
    x2 = math.cos((180+angle)/180*math.pi) * d/2 + center[0]
    y2 = math.sin((180+angle)/180*math.pi) * d/2 + center[1]
    draw.line([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)], line_color)

# Fill pie segments with defined segment colors
for i in range(n):
    angle = 360 / n * i + 360 / n / 2
    x = math.cos(angle/180*math.pi) * 20 + center[0]
    y = math.sin(angle/180*math.pi) * 20 + center[1]
    ImageDraw.floodfill(im, (x, y), segment_color(i, n))

im.save(str(n) + '_pie.png')
```

For `n = 8` pie segments, the following result is produced:

[image: 8 pie]

The first step is to replace all white pixels in the original image with the desired edge color. Of course, the assumption here is, that there are no other (white) pixels in the image. Also, this might be better done using NumPy and vectorized code, but I wanted to keep the solution Pillow-only.

Next step is to draw the (green) lines. Here, I calculate the proper coordinates of the lines' start and end using `sin` and `cos`.

The last step is to flood fill the pie segments' area, cf. [`ImageDraw.floodfill`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill). Therefore, I calculate the seed points the same way as before, but add an angular shift to hit a point exactly within the pie segment.

As you can see, `n` is variable in my solution (`n` must be even):

[image: 12 pie]
[image: 18 pie]
[image: 36 pie]

Of course, there are limitations regarding the angular resolution, most due to the small image.

Hope that helps!

---

**EDIT:** Here's a modified version to also allow for individually colored edges.

```py
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def segment_color(i_color, n_colors):
    r = int((192 - 64) / (n_colors - 1) * i_color + 64)
    g = int((224 - 128) / (n_colors - 1) * i_color + 128)
    b = 255
    return (r, g, b)


def edge_color(i_color, n_colors):
    r = 255
    g = 255 - int((224 - 32) / (n_colors - 1) * i_color + 32)
    b = 255 - int((192 - 16) / (n_colors - 1) * i_color + 16)
    return (r, g, b)


# Load image; generate ImageDraw
im = Image.open('images/vgdrD.png').convert('RGB')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
center = (int(im.width/2), int(im.height)/2)

# Number of pie segments (must be an even number)
n = 8

# Replace (all-white) edge with defined edge color
max_len = im.width + im.height
im_pix = im.load()
for i in range(n):
    mask = Image.new('L', im.size, 0)
    mask_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    angle = 360 / n * i
    x1 = math.cos(angle/180*math.pi) * max_len + center[0]
    y1 = math.sin(angle/180*math.pi) * max_len + center[1]
    angle = 360 / n * (i+1)
    x2 = math.cos(angle/180*math.pi) * max_len + center[0]
    y2 = math.sin(angle/180*math.pi) * max_len + center[1]
    mask_draw.polygon([center, (x1, y1), (x2, y2)], 255)
    mask_pix = mask.load()
    for y in range(im.height):
        for x in range(im.width):
            if (im_pix[x, y] == (255, 255, 255)) & (mask_pix[x, y] == 255):
                im_pix[x, y] = edge_color(i, n)

# Draw lines with defined line color
line_color = (0, 255, 0)
d = min(im.width, im.height) - 10
for i in range(int(n/2)):
    angle = 360 / n * i
    x1 = math.cos(angle/180*math.pi) * d/2 + center[0]
    y1 = math.sin(angle/180*math.pi) * d/2 + center[1]
    x2 = math.cos((180+angle)/180*math.pi) * d/2 + center[0]
    y2 = math.sin((180+angle)/180*math.pi) * d/2 + center[1]
    draw.line([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)], line_color)

# Fill pie segments with defined segment colors
for i in range(n):
    angle = 360 / n * i + 360 / n / 2
    x = math.cos(angle/180*math.pi) * 20 + center[0]
    y = math.sin(angle/180*math.pi) * 20 + center[1]
    ImageDraw.floodfill(im, (x, y), segment_color(i, n))

im.save(str(n) + '_pie.png')
```

[image: 8 pie new]

Binary masks for each pie segment are created, and all white pixels only within that binary mask are replaced with a defined edge color.

[image: Binary mask]

Using NumPy still seems favorable, but I was curious to do that in Pillow only.

Comment: Thank you HansHirse this is by far more than I could ask for! Is it also possible to change the color of the orange border in "n" unique colors for each segment?

Comment: @NawinNarain I was afraid, that this follow-up question will come up! ;-) That's certainly possible, for example by creating binary masks for each segment to only replace the edge pixels in that segment. But for this task, I would definitely switch to NumPy (and/or OpenCV instead of Pillow). Also, that'd be a certain amount of additional work. **EDIT:** Maybe, there's a simpler solution, also using Pillow. I'll give it a short try...

Comment: I have been using openCV before for basic image analysis so if the openCV solution is better, I should be able to use it.

Comment: You are living legend @HansHirse!